# Selenium completely unable to find visible and interactable elements

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait

I've got an appliacation which used to have a JavaScript wait function in the Selenium framework. However, this cause unsolvable problems with Angular9, and had to be removed to be replaced by something better.

Now I'm struggling with Selenium being 100% unable to find elements that are plainly visible and interactable. When I step through the code, breaking at the line clicking the element, it works fine. But even with a WebdriverWait, it's never found when running the code manually.

The markup:

```
<app-grafikk-radio>
 <hb-felt>
  <div translate="" class="hb-animation--appear hb-felt">
   <legend class="hb-legend" data-e2e-selector="hva-sporsmaal">
    <span translate="">Hva skal lånet/tilskuddet brukes til?</span>    
    <hb-hjelpetekst _nghost-ysl-c55="">    
     <div _ngcontent-ysl-c55="" class="hb-hjelpetekst">
      <button _ngcontent-ysl-c55="" type="button" class="hb-hjelpetekst-knapp" title="Åpne hjelpetekst"">
       <span _ngcontent-ysl-c55="">Åpne hjelpetekst</span><!----><!---->
       <hb-ikon _ngcontent-ysl-c55="" nghost-ysl-c56="">
        <span _ngcontent-ysl-c56="" class="hb-ikon hb-ikon-- >
         <svg _ngcontent-ysl-c56="" focusable="false">
          <use _ngcontent-ysl-c56="" xlink:href="images/sprite.symbol.svg#ikon-sporsmalstegn"></use>
         </svg>
        </span><!---->
       </hb-ikon>
      </button><!---->
     </div></hb-hjelpetekst><!---->
    </legend><!---->
    <ul class="hb-liste hb-liste--minimal hb-liste--hva">
     <li>
      <input type="radio" class="hb-grafikkradio ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" id="hva-KJOPE" data-e2e-selector="hva-KJOPE">
       <label class="hb-label" for="hva-KJOPE">Kjøpe bolig <span aria-hidden="true" class="hb-ikon hb-ikon--bolig-kjope">
        <svg focusable="false">
         <use xlink:href="/images/bolig-sprite.svg#ikon-bolig-kjope">
         </use>
        </svg>
       </span>
      </label>
     </li>
 <li>
  ...
```

The Java/Selenium code:

```
@FindBy(id = "hva-KJOPE")
public WebElement kjopeBolig;

kjopeBolig.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
//kjopeBolig.click(); //sendKeys SPACE used because click() allmost always get the "ElementInterceptedError - other element would receive the click"
```

Now, as mentioned, when stepping through the Java code and breaking at the `overtaBolig.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);` line, it works fine.

But when running it normally, it results in

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#hva-KJOPE"}

I tried waiting for the element to be clickable, like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(kjopeBolig));
element.click();
```

But that doesn't work either. It just times out:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on LINUX (5f31d37458a386bf0baea00a34aa3688)] -> id: hva-KJOPE] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Any ideas? I suspect that there is a reason why the original JavaScript wait method was used, but no one that I can get a hold of knows, the code being a few years old. Are there other methods/techniques I could try?

EDIT: Upon some more testing, it's revealed that this problem is present for ALL (radio)buttons on the same page.

Comment: I do not see an element in the HTML you posted with "hva-OVERTA" for an Id.

Comment: It's there, next to id="hva-KJOPE" - it just didn't get included in my sample above :-) I corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

A method I sometimes use when I come across this happening is using the inspect in Chrome and getting by full Xpath (which I consider to be a bit hacky always go for uniqueID's where possible but it often gets the results). 
To get it, load the html page so the element is visible in chrome-> right click -> inspect -if it doesn't highlight it immediately on the element repeat the right click inspect again -> hover over the element you want in the Elements menu within the inspect and right click the element-> copy -> full Xpath (or ID if you want to double check you have the right one with no syntax errors)- then paste it into your Driver get by method I'm not familiar with the annotated version of this however I tend use a static implementation of it like this: 
WebElement element  = DRIVER.findElement(By.xpath("paste/xpathOrId/here")); 
element.click(); 
Similar way of completing the task, just a different route, another thing you should check while you are in the inspect is that the element you want to click is in the lowest level child tag of were you want it to be i.e. if it was a button within a span, make sure its the button you've selected because sometimes elements that are held within containers start after the containers themselves and with Selenium clicking in the top left most corner of that element sometimes the click misses, if thats the case you either need to change the id of what you're selecting or use the offset method to change where the click happens manually.

Comment: Thanks. Xpath makes no difference. Also, since Selenium IS able to see the elements fine when stepping through the code, I fail to see how it could be an issue what kind of By is used?